# Laravel if then condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this query

```
        $query = Model::Select('table1.col1','table1.col2','table1.col3')
        ->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')            
        ->select('table1.id','table2.logo','table1.col2','table1.col3')
        ->whereIn(....)
        ->whereIn(....);
```

that works fine. The extra thing that i want to add is this:
If col2 value of table1 is 0 then i want to get the value of table1.col3
But when col2 value of table 1 is 1 i want to select from another table.

something like `IF table1.col2 = 0 returned_value = table1.col3 ELSE returned_value = (SELECT other_value FROM table3 WHERE CONDITION)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
->selectRaw('IF(table1.col2 = 0, table1.col3,
    (SELECT other_value FROM table3 WHERE CONDITION)) AS ...')
```